# How to create a guitar tuner in javascript?

Tags: fft

i would like to create a guitar tuner in javascript but i don't know to to do it...

Once I recorded a 2 sec fragment audio file from the microphone, I would like for example what frequency is the note played in the recorded wav file !.

How to do it ?
I've heard about FFT, but what is the main purpose of FFT ?
Because when I edit an audio wav file un sublime text i obtain a thing like this:
0A12 4A3B etc...

Am I obliged to read this hexadecimal file or an algorithm detect frequency of a wav file ? Which one ? There is a tutorial ?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and [help/on-topic] for an overview of the the sort of questions you can get help with on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Euh... In which website may I ask this question, so ?

Comment: It's really a question where you're probably better off doing some initial research on your own, maybe finding some sample code.

Comment: Also use the StackOverflow search box as this question and many similar ones have already been asked and answered before.

Comment: http://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/pitchdetect/ Is a nice demo using WebAudio and it's open source. It correlates the audio with a fixed set of sine waves (at specific frequencies) and reports the note with the highest correlation, rather than doing a full FFT.

Comment: If you want to make something like this specifically for music and don't know anything about it, well, I guess the skills required are first, learn web programming, second, implement one of the pitch estimation algorithms I showed in https://gist.github.com/fasiha/957035272009eb1c9eb370936a6af2eb

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do i get the audio frequency from my mic using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237143/how-do-i-get-the-audio-frequency-from-my-mic-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Look into [this source code](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/guitar-tuner/blob/master/src/elements/audio-processor/audio-processor.js). And then make your own guitar tuner based on audio processing functions from that code.