# How do i get the audio frequency from my mic using javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, audio, frontend, frequency

I need to create a sort of like guitar tuner.. thats recognize the sound frequencies and determines in witch chord i am actually playing. Its similar to this guitar tuner that i found online:
https://musicjungle.com.br/afinador-online
But i cant figure it out how it works because of the webpack files..I want to make this tool app backendless.. Someone have a clue about how to do this only in the front end?

i founded some old pieces of code that doesnt work together.. i need fresh ideas

Comment: any arbitrary sound ( this is in the time domain )  can be fed into a Fourier Transform ( api often called a FFT ) which will return the same information yet transformed from time domain into a representation in the frequency domain ... you feed an array of raw audio samples into this FFT call which will return back a new array in this freq domain ... then you will need to loop across this new array calculating the magnitude of each complex number stored in each element of that new array ... greatest such magnitude will be the dominant frequency of that source input audio

Answer (score 37, accepted):

There are quite a few problems to unpack here, some of which will require a bit more information as to the application. Hopefully the sheer size of this task will become apparent as this answer progresses.

As it stands, there are two problems here:

> need to create a sort of like guitar tuner..

*1. How do you detect the fundamental pitch of a guitar note and feed that information back to the user in the browser?*

and

> thats recognize the sound frequencies and determines in witch chord i am actually playing.

*2. How do you detect which chord a guitar is playing?*

This second question is definitely not a trivial one, but we'll come to it in turn. This is not a programming question, but rather a DSP question

#### Question 1: Pitch Detection in Browser

##### Breakdown

If you wish to detect the pitch of a note in the browser there are a couple sub-problems that should be split up. Shooting from the hip we have the following JavaScript browser problems:

- [how to get microphone permission?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia)
- [how to tap microhone for sample data?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AnalyserNode/getFloatTimeDomainData)
- [how to start an audio context?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext)
- [how to display a value?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [how to update a value regularly?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval)
- [how to filter audio data?](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/BiquadFilterNode)
- [how to perform pitch detection?](https://sound.eti.pg.gda.pl/student/eim/synteza/leszczyna/index_ang.htm)

  - [how to get pitch via autocorrolation?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autocorrelation)
  - [how to get picth via zero-crossing?](https://medium.com/the-seekers-project/algorithmic-frequency-pitch-detection-series-part-1-making-a-simple-pitch-tracker-using-zero-9991327897a4)
  - [how to get pitch from frequency domain?](https://ccrma.stanford.edu/%7Ejos/SimpleStrings/Plucked_Struck_String_Pitch_Estimation.html)
- [how to perform a fourier transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fft?tab=Votes)?

This is not an exhaustive list, but it should consitute the bulk of the overall problem

There is no [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), so none of the above can be assumed.

##### Implementation

A basic implementation would consist of a numeric reprenstation of a single fundamental frequency (f0) using an autocorrolation method outlined in the A. v. Knesebeck and U. Zölzer paper [1].

There are other approaches which mix and match filtering and pitch detection algorithms which I believe is far outside the scope of a reasonable answer.

**NOTE:** The [Web Audio API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API) is still [not equally implemented across all browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API#browser_compatibility). You should check each of the major browsers and make accomodations in your program. The following was tested in Google Chrome, so your mileage may (and likely will) vary in other browsers.

###### HTML

Our page should include

- an element to display frequency
- an element to initiate pitch detection

A more rounded interface would likely split the operations of

- Asking for microphone permission
- starting microphone stream
- processing microphone stream

into separate interface elements, but for brevity they will be wrapped into a single element. This gives us a basic HTML page of

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pitch Detection</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Frequency (Hz)</h1>
<h2 id="frequency">0.0</h2>
<div>
    <button onclick="startPitchDetection()">
        Start Pitch Detection
    </button>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

We are jumping the gun slightly with `<button onclick="startPitchDetection()">`. We will wrap up the operation in a single function called `startPitchDetection`

###### Pallate of variables

For an autocorrolation pitch detection approach our pallate of variables will need to include:

- the Audio context
- the microphone stream
- an Analyser Node
- an array for audio data
- an array for the corrolated signal
- an array for corrolated signal maxima
- a DOM reference to the frequency

giving us something like

```js
let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
let microphoneStream = null;
let analyserNode = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
let audioData = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);;
let corrolatedSignal = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);;
let localMaxima = new Array(10);
const frequencyDisplayElement = document.querySelector('#frequency');
```

Some value are left `null` as they will not be known until the microphone stream has been activated. The `10` in `let localMaxima = new Array(10);` is a little arbitrary. This array will store the distance in samples between consecutive maxima of the corrolated signal.

###### Main script

Our `<button>` element has an `onclick` function of `startPitchDetection`, so that will be required. We will also need

- an update function (for updating the display)
- an autocorrolation function that returns a pitch

However, the first thing we have to do is ask for permission to use the microphone. [To achieve this we use `navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia), which will returm a [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). Embellishing on what is outlined in the MDN documentation this gives us something roughly looking like

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({audio: true})
.then((stream) => {
  /* use the stream */
})
.catch((err) => {
  /* handle the error */
});
```

Great! Now we can start adding our main functionality to the `then` function.

Our order of events should be

- Start microphone stream
- connect microphone stream to the analyser node
- set a timed callback to

  - get the latest time domain audio data from the Analyser Node
  - get the autocorrolation derived pitch estimate
  - update html element with the value

On top of that, add a log of the error from the `catch` method.

This can then all be wrapped into the `startPitchDetection` function, giving something like:

```js
function startPitchDetection()
{
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: true})
        .then((stream) =>
        {
            microphoneStream = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
            microphoneStream.connect(analyserNode);

            audioData = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);
            corrolatedSignal = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);

            setInterval(() => {
                analyserNode.getFloatTimeDomainData(audioData);

                let pitch = getAutocorrolatedPitch();

                frequencyDisplayElement.innerHTML = `${pitch}`;
            }, 300);
        })
        .catch((err) =>
        {
            console.log(err);
        });
}
```

The update interval for `setInterval` of `300` is arbitrary. A little experimentation will dictate which interval is best for you. You may even wish to give the user control of this, but that is outside the scope of thise question.

The next step is to actually define what `getAutocorrolatedPitch()` does, so lets actually breakdown what autocorrolation is.

Autocorrelation is the process of [convolving](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) a signal with itself. Any time the result goes from a positive rate of change to a negative rate of change is defined as a *local maximum*. The number of samples between the start of the corrolated signal to the first maximum should be the period in samples of `f0`. We can continue to look for subsequent maxima and take an average which should improve accuracy slightly. Some frequencies do not have a period of whole samples, for instance `440` Hz at a sample rate of `44100` Hz has a period of `100.227`. We technichally could never accurately detect this frequency of `440` Hz by taking a single maximum, the result would always be either `441` Hz (`44100/100`) or `436` Hz (`44100/101`).

For our autocorrolation function, we'll need

- a track of how many maxima that have been detected
- the mean distance between maxima

Our function should first perform the autocorrolation, find the sample positions of local maximum and then calculate the mean distance between these maxima. This give a function looking like:

```js
function getAutocorrolatedPitch()
{
    // First: autocorrolate the signal

    let maximaCount = 0;

    for (let l = 0; l < analyserNode.fftSize; l++) {
        corrolatedSignal[l] = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < analyserNode.fftSize - l; i++) {
            corrolatedSignal[l] += audioData[i] * audioData[i + l];
        }
        if (l > 1) {
            if ((corrolatedSignal[l - 2] - corrolatedSignal[l - 1]) < 0
                && (corrolatedSignal[l - 1] - corrolatedSignal[l]) > 0) {
                localMaxima[maximaCount] = (l - 1);
                maximaCount++;
                if ((maximaCount >= localMaxima.length))
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    // Second: find the average distance in samples between maxima

    let maximaMean = localMaxima[0];

    for (let i = 1; i < maximaCount; i++)
        maximaMean += localMaxima[i] - localMaxima[i - 1];

    maximaMean /= maximaCount;

    return audioCtx.sampleRate / maximaMean;
}
```

###### Problems

Once you have implemented this you may find there are actually a couple of problems.

- The frequency result is a bit erratic
- the display method is not intuitive for tuning purposes

The erratic result is down to the fact that autocorrolation by itself is not a perfect solution. You will need to experiment with first filtering the signal and aggregating other methods. You could also try limiting the signal or only analyse the signal when it is above a certain threshold. You could also increase the rate at which you perform the detection and average out the results.

Secondly, the method for display is limited. Musicians would not be appreciative of a simple numerical result, rather, some kind of graphical feedback would be more intuitive. Again, that is outside the scope of the question.

###### Full page and script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Pitch Detection</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Frequency (Hz)</h1>
<h2 id="frequency">0.0</h2>
<div>
    <button onclick="startPitchDetection()">
        Start Pitch Detection
    </button>
</div>
<script>
    let audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();
    let microphoneStream = null;
    let analyserNode = audioCtx.createAnalyser()
    let audioData = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);;
    let corrolatedSignal = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);;
    let localMaxima = new Array(10);
    const frequencyDisplayElement = document.querySelector('#frequency');

    function startPitchDetection()
    {
        navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia ({audio: true})
            .then((stream) =>
            {
                microphoneStream = audioCtx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
                microphoneStream.connect(analyserNode);

                audioData = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);
                corrolatedSignal = new Float32Array(analyserNode.fftSize);

                setInterval(() => {
                    analyserNode.getFloatTimeDomainData(audioData);

                    let pitch = getAutocorrolatedPitch();

                    frequencyDisplayElement.innerHTML = `${pitch}`;
                }, 300);
            })
            .catch((err) =>
            {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    function getAutocorrolatedPitch()
    {
        // First: autocorrolate the signal

        let maximaCount = 0;

        for (let l = 0; l < analyserNode.fftSize; l++) {
            corrolatedSignal[l] = 0;
            for (let i = 0; i < analyserNode.fftSize - l; i++) {
                corrolatedSignal[l] += audioData[i] * audioData[i + l];
            }
            if (l > 1) {
                if ((corrolatedSignal[l - 2] - corrolatedSignal[l - 1]) < 0
                    && (corrolatedSignal[l - 1] - corrolatedSignal[l]) > 0) {
                    localMaxima[maximaCount] = (l - 1);
                    maximaCount++;
                    if ((maximaCount >= localMaxima.length))
                        break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Second: find the average distance in samples between maxima

        let maximaMean = localMaxima[0];

        for (let i = 1; i < maximaCount; i++)
            maximaMean += localMaxima[i] - localMaxima[i - 1];

        maximaMean /= maximaCount;

        return audioCtx.sampleRate / maximaMean;
    }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### Question 2: Detecting multiple notes

At this point I think we can all agree that this answer has gotten a little out of hand. So far we've just covered a single method of pitch detection. See Ref [2, 3, 4] for some suggestions of algorithms for multiple `f0` detection.

In essence, this problem would come down to detecting all `f0`s and looking up the resulting notes against a dictionary of chords. For that, there should at least be a little work done on your part. Any questions about the DSP should probably be pointed toward https://dsp.stackexchange.com. You will be spoiled for choice on [questions regarding pitch detection algorithms](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pitch)

##### References

1. A. v. Knesebeck and U. Zölzer, "[Comparison of pitch trackers for real-time guitar effects](http://dafx10.iem.at/papers/VonDemKnesebeckZoelzer_DAFx10_P102.pdf)", in *Proceedings of the 13th International Conference on Digital Audio Effects (DAFx-10), Graz, Austria, September 6-10*, 2010.
2. A. P. Klapuri, "A perceptually motivated multiple-F0 estimation method," *IEEE Workshop on Applications of Signal Processing to Audio and Acoustics*, 2005., 2005, pp. 291-294, doi: 10.1109/ASPAA.2005.1540227.
3. A. P. Klapuri, ["Multiple fundamental frequency estimation based on harmonicity and spectral smoothness,"](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Edpwe/papers/Klap03-multif0.pdf) in *IEEE Transactions on Speech and Audio Processing, vol. 11, no. 6, pp. 804-816, Nov. 2003*, doi: 10.1109/TSA.2003.815516.
4. A. P. Klapuri, "[Multipitch estimation and sound separation by the spectral smoothness principle](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=940384)," *2001 IEEE International Conference on Acoustics, Speech, and Signal Processing. Proceedings (Cat. No.01CH37221)*, 2001, pp. 3381-3384 vol.5, doi: 10.1109/ICASSP.2001.940384.
5. A. M. Stark and M. D. Plumbley, ["Real-Time Chord Recognition For Live Performance"](http://www.adamstark.co.uk/pdf/papers/chord-recognition-ICMC-2009.pdf), In Proceedings of the 2009 International Computer Music Conference (ICMC 2009), Montreal, Canada, 16-21 August 2009.
6. Alain de Cheveigné, Hideki Kawahara; [YIN, a fundamental frequency estimator for speech and music](http://audition.ens.fr/adc/pdf/2002_JASA_YIN.pdf). J. Acoust. Soc. Am. 1 April 2002; 111 (4): 1917–1930.

Comment: “ At this point I think we can all agree that this answer has gotten a little out of hand.” It was one of the most interesting ones I’ve read recently though! 

Comment: Very nice answer!  I suspect robust polyphonic chord recognition is an order of magnitude harder particularly when mixed with real-world tunings, and an area of active research with a mix of DSP and AI/ML-based solutions out there.  On the DSP side this one looked interesting: https://silo.tips/download/automatic-chord-recognition-from-audio-using-enhanced-pitch-class-profile and points to a range of sources.  I suspect a really robust solution will need to also understand context (the key of the overall piece, for example).  All this would be way too much for an SO answer.

Comment: For an insight into the mechanics of polyphonic "chord" recognition, the patent details of one such device may be of interest and can be found at https://patents.google.com/patent/US8334449B2/en

Comment: The singular of "maxima" is "maximum". Thank you for the wonderful writeup!

Answer (score 1):

I suppose it'll depend how you're building your application. Hard to help without much detail around specs. Though, here are a few options for you.

There are a few stream options, for example;

- [mic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mic)

Or if you're using React;

- [react-mic](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mic)

Or if you're wanting to go real basic with some vanilla JS;

- [Web Fundamentals: Recording Audio](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/media/recording-audio)