# How to extract realtime frequency from a sound from microphone in react native?

Tags: react-native, audio, frequency

I need to extract real-time frequency(and other data also if possible like amplitude etc) from a sound from a microphone like an app [GuitarTuna](https://yousician.com/guitartuna). Is there any library or API using which I can achieve this thing in react native?

Comment: With react native, possibly a WebView and [WebAudio](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Audio_API), at which point it’s not “native” anymore. Given you reference a tuner , if your follow-up is _how do I get frequency_ my response is [_how deep do you want to go?_](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69237143/how-do-i-get-the-audio-frequency-from-my-mic-using-javascript)